# Property 'frame' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'

Tags: objective-c

Here is what i am trying:

```
 _maskingLayer = [ CALayer layer] 
 _maskingLayer.frame  << shows the error
```

Error :

Property 'frame' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'

Seems like i need to import some package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select Project File-->Target-->Build Phases
[image]
Then add `QuartzCore.framework`
And use below import in your file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing import for QuartzCore framework:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```