# Property 'frame' cannot be found in forward class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

First: I'm very new to cocoa development. I guess my problem is something very obvious.

I need to know the size of my WebView after loading. For that I've found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679583/1146700) already, but I have a Problem. Here's the relevant piece of my code.

The App delegate:

```
    @implementation MDAppDelegate

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

      //set ourselves as the frame load delegate so we know when the window loads
      [self.webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];

      // set the request variable, which works and then load the content into the webView
      [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];

    }

    - (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame
    {
      NSLog(@"webView:didFinishLoadForFrame");
      if([webFrame isEqual:[self.webView mainFrame]]) {
        // some code ...
        // and at some point I want to get the frame property of self.window
        NSRect windowFrame = self.window.frame;
      }
    }
```

The window property is defined in the header file of the app delegate:

```
    @interface MDAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
      @property (weak) IBOutlet MDTransparentWindow *window;
      @property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
    @end
```

I found the answer to (so it would seem) a [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14385364/1146700). The solution there is to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`and also link the framework in the Build Phases tab. I did this, but the problem remains. I also cleaned my project (as of now I still don't really know what cleaning does, but sometimes it helps) with no result.

The window is an instance of my own class `TransparentWindow` which is subclassing `NSWindow`. When I start writing `self.f` in the subclass implementation file xcode automatically suggests `frame`. But this is not happening when I write `self.window.f` in the `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame` method.

As I said, I'm new to cocoa development. Any hints, what I might have missed?

Comment: Does you code compile? Is this just an issue of not working autocompletion?

Comment: it doesn't compile. Xcode also shows me the errors in the corresponding lines where I use `self.window.frame` with the described error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually get this message if you only did a forward declaration of a class, like

```
@class MyPhantasticClass;
```

The compiler knows that it is a class, but doesn't know any of it's methods. You need to include the right header file.

Comment: Thank you. I included the header file of my NSWindow subclass in the app delagate file and now it works.